# How clone HG/Mercurial remote repository in Ubuntu and run sh file?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, mercurial

I would like to clone remote  HG/Mercurial repository and run from terminal sh file. Would like to know which steps needed in more details. So, first I think need to install mercurial. Do I need the mercurial server or just mercurial?

So in Ubuntu the command is

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial-server
```

Then need to create SSH key and add to remote repository (Ubuntu):

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-add
ssh-copy-id  ...
```

True? any more help and details?

Answer (score 2):

> True? any more help and details?

No. Just install `mercurial`:

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

Then clone, similar way like with `git` or whatever, if it is public accessible repo:

```
$ hg clone https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hello my-hello
```

If it is not, you would need to:

- set the public key using different channel (web UI?)
- add password

It depends on the service/server.

Comment: It is not public accessible repo. But I have user name and password. so I need to create SSH key and add to remote repo. How I should do that? Then I can clone it using ssh://user_name@repo.name//../file_name